# Fill NaN values in a pandas dataframe with values of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, fill

I want to fill nan values in a movie dataframe with values of another dataframe

df_amazon:

```
 tittle  genre  director
   'a'    'b'     nan
```

df_disney:

```
 tittle  genre  director
   'a'    'b'     'c'
```

The disney and others dataframe has similar movies an uniques movies. I need to find the movie with null value in amazon, search the same movie in another dataframe and replace the values.

Answer (score 1):

I think [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) will work:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_amazon = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['a'], 'genre': ['b'], 'director': [None]})
df_disney = pd.DataFrame({'title': ['a'], 'genre': ['b'], 'director': ['c']})
print(df_amazon.fillna(df_disney))
```